# How to make /mnt/resource readable/writable but other users in Azure Linux VM?

Tags: linux, azure, centos7

Right now /mnt/resource is owned by root and only root can read/write. How can I make this readable/writable by other users on the system?

And this should be persistent (i.e. after system restart it should still work)

Answer (score 1):

> How to make /mnt/resource readable/writable but other users in Azure Linux VM?

To do this you need to use a command similar to the following:

```
chown other_user /mnt/resource
```

> And this should be persistent (i.e. after system restart it should still work)

Based on [this documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-agent-user-guide/), the Azure Linux Agent (/usr/sbin/waagent) does the following:

> • Manages the resource disk
>
> • Formats and mounts the resource disk

Upon provisioning an instance (starting/restarting) the device `/dev/sdb1` will be mounted by waagent upon boot based on the setting `ResourceDisk.MountPoint=` in `/etc/waagent.conf`, defaulting to `/mnt/resource`. You can verify this by typing the command `cat /var/log/waagent.log | grep sdb1` after stopping and starting an instance should show something like this:

```
2016/06/17 09:06:42 Resource disk (/dev/sdb1) is mounted at /mnt/resource with fstype ext4
```

Because waagent creates the mount some time after the boot, setting permissions immediately upon boot will not work. (I've experienced a race condition where I created a directory in `/mnt/resource` only to have it deleted when the mount occurs.)

You can create a service which will wait until `/dev/sdb1` is mounted to `/mnt/resource/` then change permissions as needed.

One way would be to have a script similar to the following run as an init script:

```
#!/bin/sh

LOG=/tmp/startup.log
while [ `mount | grep /mnt/resource | wc -l` -lt 1 ];
do
    echo "Waiting for mount to be created by waagent..." >> ${LOG}
    sleep 5
done
echo "Changing /mnt/resource permissions..." >> ${LOG}
chown other_user /mnt/resource
```

Comment: `/dev/sdb1` is the mount point for the local scratch disk. It is not relevant when mounting an attached disk. And `waagent` doesn't impact mounted disks.

Comment: @DavidMakogon If the `waagent` doesn't mount the disk as I have described, can you please explain to me what does make the mount?

Answer (score 0):

Chown and Chmod are the commands to achieve this.

Probably easier just to read this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod

Comment: Yes, but will these persists after reboot? As that folder looks like it's mounted by https://github.com/Azure/WALinuxAgent

Comment: I think as long as your mount point is persistent then it should

Comment: Im not sure how WALinuxAgent will affect this, sorry.

Comment: Just tested, and just with chmod after reboot permissions are reset to being readonly for rest of the users, only root can write there.

Comment: You could normally put the permissions in your etc/fstab file with the mount config but i'm really not sure with this agent thing, sorry.

Comment: Yea, apparently it has a config file, but you can only specify where to mount it (/mnt/resource by default) but not what permissions to give to that folder.

Answer (score 0):

/mnt/resource WILL NOT PERSIST no matter what you do with it [Documentation](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mast/2013/12/06/understanding-the-temporary-drive-on-windows-azure-virtual-machines/)